# Template parameters not being replaced in certain files for multi-project template (.NET 8, ASP.NET Core, VS 2022)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-templates

**My Scenario**

- VS 17.8.7
- .NET 8

I have the following ASP.NET Core Hosted Blazor WASM project:

[image]

I am trying to export it as a multi-project template. To do this, I do the following:

1. Find/Replace all instances of my current project name with `$ext_safeprojectname$`.
2. Export each project as a Template individually.
3. Extract the files from the resulting .zip folders and place in a new directory.
4. Add a `MyTemplate.vstemplate` file to the root of the new folder.

Here is the resulting folder structure:

[image]

Here are the contents of the `.vstemplate` file:

```xml
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>My Wasm Template</Name>
        <Description>...</Description>
        <Icon>Icon.ico</Icon>
        <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
        <ProjectCollection>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Client" CopyParameters="true">
                MyWasmTemplate.Client\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Server" CopyParameters="true">
                MyWasmTemplate.Server\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Data" CopyParameters="true">
                MyWasmTemplate.Data\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Shared" CopyParameters="true">
                MyWasmTemplate.Shared\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
        </ProjectCollection>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

**Result**

When I create a new project using this template, the new project name correctly replaces most of the `$ext_safeprojectname$` instances, except the following files in the client project:

`_Imports.razor`:

```cs
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Http
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using $ext_safeprojectname$.Client
@using $ext_safeprojectname$.Client.Layout
@using $ext_safeprojectname$.Shared
@using MudBlazor
```

`MainLayout.razor`:

```html
...
<PageTitle>$ext_safeprojectname$</PageTitle>
...
    <p class="text-nowrap">$ext_safeprojectname$</p>
...
```

and one other blazor component:

```cs
@page "/blogs"
@using $ext_safeprojectname$.Shared.Dtos
@inject HttpClient Http
```

Why are these template parameters not being replaced in these files? They're being replaced everywhere else properly, even within the client project.